# problem finding g++ program, despite it being installed

Tags: software-installation, g++

```
gcc version 5.3.0 20151204 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04)
```

I have a problem with g++

When I search for g++ I find nothing!

So I tried to install it; it seems like g++ is already installed and it's the newest one!

```
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:~$ which g++
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:~$ sudo apt-get install g++
[sudo] password for arubu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version.
g++ set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgranite-common libgranite1 libkeybinder-3.0-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:~$ g++ -v
The program 'g++' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: Also check `dpkg -l g++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should force the re-installation of the `g++` package; this will restore the appropriate symbolic links:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install g++
```

Once this is done you should find that `/usr/bin/g++` exists once again and is a symbolic link to `g++-5`.

Answer (score 4):

The `/usr/bin/g++` is a symbolic link to the real executable which is `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++`. I guess your symbolic link is missing. Try and see if the latter file exists but the former does not. Then you can fix it manually by issuing `sudo ln -sv /usr/bin/X86_64-linux-gnu-g++ /usr/bin/g++`.

This answer is taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558668/g-not-working-need-to-change-path-variable).